# I want refresh AntiForgeryToken value for each ajax request, how do I do it in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I am developing a web application using ASP.Net MVC and for CSRF Prevention I am using AntiForgeryToken() provided by framework.
I have a ajax form which is submitted to server, but each time when I submit the form the value of AntiForgeryToken is always same for each request. When the form is submitted, server returns boolean variable - depending upon the returned value I do some other processing and clear the form values in jquery in OnSuccess method of ajax form.

In order to prevent CSRF attack form the same network segment, token value must be changed for each and every request passing to the server. So is there any way I can refersh the token value using javascript/jquery?